# ProjectEuler#3: Why is it telling me that this division breaks even when it doesn't?

Tags: c

For smaller numbers, my code seems to find the highest prime number ok. However, for this particular larger number it thinks 600851475143 is divisible by 7 (It is not a factor, which I verified using wolfram).

My algorithm to solve the problem is as follows:

1) Let p=value for which we want to find the immediately smaller prime number.
2) Check if p is prime using isComposite(p)
3) If p is composite, decrement p and try again
4) Stop when found a prime number

isComposite(p) works as follows:
1) Let i=2
2) Given some number 'limit', check to see if i divides 'limit'
3) If it does, then return i (Originally, it was 1 but I wanted to check what it think divides 'limit')
4) If i does not divide limit, increment i and repeat starting from 2, stopping when i>= sqrt(limit). This is because factors of a number, if they exist, occur in pairs in which one value is less than sqrt(number).

Here is the call tree:

```
printf("P3:%lu\n",p3v2(600851475143)); //Print the highest prime
```

Here is the p3v2() function:

```
unsigned long p3v2(unsigned long limit)
{
    unsigned long i = limit;

    while(i>1)
    {
        printf("Checking %lu\n", i);
        if(!(isComposite(i) != 0))
        {
            printf("%lu is prime!\n", isComposite(i)); 
            return i;
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("%lu is composite!\n", isComposite(i)); 
            i--; 
        }
    }
    return -1; 
}
```

And isComposite()

```
unsigned long isComposite(unsigned int limit)
    {
        unsigned long i = 2; 
        unsigned long searchUpperBound = (unsigned long)sqrt(limit); //Only need to search up to sqrt(limit) to see if there is a factor
        while(i<=searchUpperBound)                                   //See if numbers up through searchUpperBound divides limit
        {
            if(limit%i==0) //If factor found
                return i;  
            else 
                i++; 
        }
        return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: `600851475143` is a signed `int` constant and will overflow the permissable range for `int`. You can make it an unsigned ´long` constant by appending `ul`: `600851475143ul`.

Comment: @MOehm If `long` is 32-bit, the type of integer constant `600851475143` is `long long`, not `int`.

Comment: Doh! I just realized that my code finds the immediately smaller prime number next to 'limit', which isn't what the problem asks for! 

But the suggestions did help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unsigned long` is probably 32-bit on your machine. `600851475143` (hex `0x8BE589EAC7`) doesn't fit in an `unsigned long`, it's actually `0xE589EAC7` (decimal `3851020999`, which is dividable by `7`)  that is used in calculation.

The solution is to use `unsigned long long` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that unsigned longs are 64-bit on your machine and unsigned ints are 32-bit.  Otherwise your printfs would probably be printing weird numbers already.  If this is all true, the culprit is this line:

```
unsigned long isComposite(unsigned int limit)
```

Here, you should make `limit` an unsigned long:

```
unsigned long isComposite(unsigned long limit)
```

However, I would suggest you remove all your unsigned longs and replace them with `uint64_t`:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t isComposite(uint64_t limit)
```